# Recursively append files to zip archive in python

Tags: python, recursion, zip

In Python 2.7.4 on Windows, if I have a directory structure that follows:

```
test/foo/a.bak
test/foo/b.bak
test/foo/bar/c.bak
test/d.bak
```

And I use the following to add them to an **existing** archive such that 'd.bak' is at the root of the archive:

```
import zipfile
import os.path
import fnmatch

def find_files(directory, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
                yield filename

if __name__=='__main__':
    z = zipfile.ZipFile("testarch.zip", "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for filename in find_files('test', '*.*'):
        print 'Found file:', filename
        z.write(filename, os.path.basename(filename), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    z.close()
```

The directory of the zip file is flat. It creates the `foo/` directory ***only*** if a sub-directory exists in it (If I exclude `test/foo/bar/c.bak`, it does not create the directory. If it is included, `foo/` is created but not `foo/bar/` if that makes sense), but no sub-directories or files:

```
foo/
a.bak
b.bak
c.bak
d.bak
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you're explicitly asking it to flatten all the paths:

```
z.write(filename, os.path.basename(filename), zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)
```

If you look at [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile#zipfile.ZipFile.write), the default `arcname` is:

> the same as `filename`, but without a drive letter and with leading path separators removed

But you're overriding that with `os.path.basename(filename)`. (If you don't know what [`basename`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path#os.path.basename) does, it returns "the last pathname component". If you don't want just the last pathname component, don't call `basename`.)

If you just do `z.write('test/foo/bar/c.bak')`, it will create a zip entry named `test/foo/bar/c.bak`, but if you do `z.write('test/foo/bar/c.bak', 'c.bak')`, it will create a zip entry named `c.bak`. Since you do that for all of the entries, the whole thing ends up flattened.

Comment: Ok, I see now. Is there a way to set the *contents* of the `test/` directory as the root, instead of the directory itself?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The contents of `test` are 0 or more files or directories, and the root has to be a directory. Do you mean you want `test` rather than its parent to be root—that is, you want paths relative to `'test/'`? That's just `os.path.relpath(path, 'test')`. Or, if you want to remove just the first component, you can `os.path.split` all the way down to a list of `components`, then `os.path.join(*components[1:])`. (If you want the latter, and need more explanation, I can edit it into the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. As **abarnet** pointed out, I had misread the docs on zipfiles. Using the following function, I can create the correct archive name for the zip file:

```
def createArchName(path):
    line = path
    if "\\" in line:
        ''' windows '''
        discard, val = line.split("\\", 1)
        return val
    else:
        ''' unix '''
        discard, val = line.split("/", 1)
        return val
```

For those interested, the full code is as follows:

```
import urllib2
import zipfile
import os.path
import fnmatch

def find_files(directory, pattern):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for basename in files:
            if fnmatch.fnmatch(basename, pattern):
                filename = os.path.join(root, basename)
                yield filename

def createArchName(path):
    line = path
    if "\\" in line:
        ''' windows '''
        discard, val = line.split("\\", 1)
        return val
    else:
        ''' unix '''
        discard, val = line.split("/", 1)
        return val


if __name__=='__main__':
    if not os.path.exists("test"):
        os.mkdir("test")

    z = zipfile.ZipFile("testarch.zip", "a", zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    for filename in find_files('test', '*.*'):
        archname = createArchName(filename)
        print 'Found file:', archname
        z.write(filename, archname, zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

    z.close()
```